# Is it possible to change Passenger Ruby version without recompiling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

I tried changing the default `ruby` command to 1.9.2 but Passenger keeps running 1.8.7

Is Passenger compiled with Ruby embedded?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Please elaborate on how you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 16):

To set the Ruby version add this line to your vhost file:

```
PassengerRuby /path/to/the/ruby/version/you/want/to/use
```

Comment: @marimaf it depends entirely on your hosting setup.

Comment: I just ran $locate vhost and didnt get any files named just vhost. All I got where some apache http_vhost.h, mod_vhost_alias.so and httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Well, like I said everything would depend on your setup. The conf is what you are looking for. If you want more info you should ask a new question on serverfault.com

Answer (score 7):

Whenever a "bundle update" updates the version of the passenger gem, I do

```
sudo su -
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

At the end of that process, it spits out the full blob of stuff that you need to put at the top or your Apache config.  E.g. something like:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/gems/passenger-3.0.9
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/ruby
```

I update the blob of stuff, restart Apache and all seems well.

I imagine that this same process is necessary after updating Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Set PassengerRuby before the `<Directory>` tag.

Example:

```
PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/ruby
```

It is working for me!

Find more detail in [this post](http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/).