# Ubuntu, Apache, Passenger, Ruby/Rails on Ec2 - passenger-install-apache2-module broken pipe

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, passenger

Passenger is currently running the wrong version of Ruby.  I have installed the newer version 2.1.5 but cannot get this command to finish compiling.

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

**Passanger Version**

```
Phusion Passenger version 4.0.55
```

**Apache Version**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

**RVM Version**

```
rvm 1.26.4 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

**Ruby Versions**

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

**echo $PATH**

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin
```

**which gem**

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/gem
```

**RVM INFO**

```
ruby-2.1.5:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux ip-172-31-33-140 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/14.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.4 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "14 hours 8 minutes 49 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/ubuntu/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.5p273"
    date:         "2014-11-13"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2014-11-13 revision 48405"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5"
    ruby:         "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5"
    IRBRC:        "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf**

```
PassengerDefaul Ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

**The Problem**

I would like to run passenger-install-apache2-module un order to get generate the mod_passenger.so for the the ruby version so that I can set it in the apache2.conf.

Currently

**locate mod_passenger.so**

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

**The Error**

When I go into the new ruby gem folder and try to run the install passenger command.  It compiles for a very long time and then says broken pipe.  I've tried the following commands and have gotten the same error

```
rvmsudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
sudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module 
rvmsudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
sudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I have uninstalled and installed passenger between efforts as well.  Here is the error.

```
    Welcome to the Phusion Passenger Apache 2 module installer, v4.0.55.

    This installer will guide you through the entire installation process. It
    shouldn't take more than 3 minutes in total.

    Here's what you can expect from the installation process:

     1. The Apache 2 module will be installed for you.
     2. You'll learn how to configure Apache.
     3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.

    Don't worry if anything goes wrong. This installer will advise you on how to
    solve any problems.

    Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.


    --------------------------------------------

    Which languages are you interested in?

    Use <space> to select.
    If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

       (*)  Ruby
       ( )  Python
     > ( )  Node.js
       ( )  Meteor

--------------------------------------------

Checking for required software...

 * Checking for C compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/cc
 * Checking for C++ compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/c++
 * Checking for Curl development headers with SSL support...
      Found: yes
      curl-config location: /usr/bin/curl-config
      Header location: /usr/include/curl/curl.h
      Version: libcurl 7.35.0
      Usable: yes
      Supports SSL: yes
 * Checking for OpenSSL development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
 * Checking for Zlib development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/include/zlib.h
 * Checking for Apache 2...
      Found: yes
      Location of httpd: /usr/sbin/apache2
      Apache version: 2.4.7
 * Checking for Apache 2 development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location of apxs2: /usr/bin/apxs2
 * Checking for Rake (associated with /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby)...
      Found: yes
      Location: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/rake
 * Checking for OpenSSL support for Ruby...
      Found: yes
 * Checking for RubyGems...
      Found: yes
 * Checking for Ruby development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h
 * Checking for rack...
      Found: yes
 * Checking for Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/apr-1-config
      Version: 1.5.1
 * Checking for Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/apu-1-config
      Version: 1.5.3

--------------------------------------------

Sanity checking Apache installation...
All good!

--------------------------------------------
Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55
# /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/rake RELEASE=yes apache2:clean apache2
rm -rf buildout/cache
rm -rf buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a buildout/common/libboost_oxt
rm -f buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o
rm -f buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/Base64.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/LargeFiles.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsStarter.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsBase.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/fib.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/jsoncpp.o
rm -f buildout/common/libpassenger_common/agents/LoggingAgent/FilterSupport.o
rm -rf buildout/common/libpassenger_common
rm -rf buildout/agents/
rm -rf buildout/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a buildout/apache2/module_libboost_oxt
rm -f buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils.o
rm -f buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/Base64.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/LargeFiles.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/AgentsStarter.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/AgentsBase.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/fib.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/jsoncpp.o
rm -f buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/agents/LoggingAgent/FilterSupport.o
rm -rf buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common
rm -rf buildout/apache2/Configuration.o buildout/apache2/Bucket.o buildout/apache2/Hooks.o buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.o buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
mkdir -p buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o -c ext/common/Logging.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o -c ext/common/Exceptions.cpp
mkdir -p buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o -c ext/common/Utils/SystemTime.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o -c ext/common/Utils/StrIntUtils.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o -c ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils.o -c ext/common/Utils.cpp
mkdir -p buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -pipe -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o -c ext/common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.cpp
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

**Passenger Error Log**
Here is most of what passenger says in the browser, as you can see it is still running 2.1.2

```
Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:385:in `validate_ruby!'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:258:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:361:in `running_bundler'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:256:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
Application root
/etc/projects/myapp
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
User and groups
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),102(netdev)
Environment variables
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
rvm_bin_path = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
SHELL = /bin/bash
IRBRC = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXdOCV4S
SERVER_PORT = 80
MY_RUBY_HOME = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
USER = ubuntu
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /etc/projects/myapp/public
_system_type = Linux
REQUEST_URI = /
rvm_path = /home/ubuntu/.rvm
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = production
REMOTE_PORT = 49231
rvm_prefix = /home/ubuntu
PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
WSGI_ENV = production
SERVER_ADMIN = [no address given]
PWD = /etc/projects/myapp
LANG = C
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
NODE_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/node_lib
_system_arch = x86_64
NODE_ENV = production
_system_version = 14.04
REMOTE_ADDR = 108.49.67.170
rvm_version = 1.26.4 (latest)
SERVER_NAME = 54.191.134.234
HOME = /home/ubuntu
SHLVL = 0
RAILS_ENV = production
rvm_ruby_string = ruby-2.1.5
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
LOGNAME = ubuntu
QUERY_STRING = 
SERVER_ADDR = 172.31.33.140
GEM_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
rvm_delete_flag = 0
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
RUBY_VERSION = ruby-2.1.5
_system_name = Ubuntu
_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
Ulimits
Unknown
System metrics
------------- General -------------
Kernel version    : 3.13.0-24-generic
Uptime            : 121d 19h 35m 27s
Load averages     : 0.02%, 0.14%, 0.19%
Fork rate         : unknown

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :    1
Average CPU usage :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
I/O pressure      :   0%
  CPU 1           :   0%
Interference from other VMs:   0%
  CPU 1                    :   0%

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :    588 MB
RAM used          :     96 MB (16%)
RAM free          :    492 MB
Swap total        :   1023 MB
Swap used         :     57 MB (6%)
Swap free         :    966 MB
Swap in           : unknown
Swap out          : unknown

General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 2.1.2
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.4.2
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 2
MINOR = 1
TEENY = 0
PATCHLEVEL = 95
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-2.1.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorarchhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
sitearchhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux
vendorhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH = 
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2' '--enable-load-relative' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared'
vendorarchdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
vendordir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
```

I've been looking at a lot of material that seemed to help, but I've kept running into the same issue in the end.
https://rvm.io/deployment/passenger
[Is it possible to change Passenger Ruby version without recompiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102095/is-it-possible-to-change-passenger-ruby-version-without-recompiling)
http://terratakashi.logdown.com/posts/190823-use-different-rvm-gemset-for-rails-app-on-apache-server

I'm inexperienced when it comes to the ops work and server work so I'm not sure if memory allocation or usage could be part of the issue, and if it is then I'm not sure how to work around that or fix it...

**Swap**

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swap                                   file        1048572 58752   -1
```

Any guidance would be great!

**UPDATE**

*I never got the compiler to complete but at some point along doing the following steps per @BMW guidance, I reloaded the server and the site no longer had Passenger and Gemfile ruby version conflicts.  My apache.conf is still not accurate, but things are working so :)*

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-140:/etc/apache2$ source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-140:/etc/apache2$ sudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

**which passenger-config**

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-config
```

**rvm use 2.1.5**

```
Using /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
```

**/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-config --ruby-command**

```
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55/bin/passenger start

## Notes for RVM users
Do you want to know which command to use for a different Ruby interpreter? 'rvm use' that Ruby interpreter, then re-run 'passenger-config --ruby-command'.
```

Comment: run it with root permission :-)

Comment: @BMW I had my fingers crossed that would help too!  I've run it with sudo passenger-install-apache2-modulea which says no command, and I've run it with rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module which acted the same as passenger-install-apache2-module.

Comment: then give the full path of `passenger-install-apache2-module` with sudo command

Comment: @BMW I ran .... rvmsudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module ... same results, the installer runs, then eventually after some time says "Broken Pipe"

Comment: try this:  `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`; then run `sudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module`

Comment: ah yes, I think you are on to something, it returned ```/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory```

Comment: Any other ideas?  I just tried installing from the inside the gem file and again, no success.. ```rvmsudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module``` and ```sudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.55/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module```

Comment: If you install with command `gem install passenger`, which version will you get ? Is package `passenger` same as `passenger-install-ap‌​ache2-module`?

Comment: ```ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-140:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5$ gem install passenger ```
```Building native extensions.  This could take a while...```
```Successfully installed passenger-4.0.55```
```1 gem installed```

Comment: @BMW ... thanks for stickin with me!  The compiler never completed...but the site is working now and no longer saying  Passenger and my gemfile have conflicting ruby version...thanks!!!

Comment: That's great, I make a conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wit this issue `Write failed: Broken pipe`, here are some steps you can try:

```
1. run it with root permission with full path.

2. if you manage ruby with rvm, you need source it first 

    source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

3. if the package can be installed directly with `gem install`, just do it.
```

Hope these help.